# How to install neovim 0.5.0 with homebrew Brewfile?

Tags: homebrew

How can I install `neovim 0.5.0` with `Brewfile`? I previously used `brew install neovim --HEAD` to get the latest build of neovim. As I have migrated to use `Brewfile`, this is the code I use for installing `neovim` in `Brewfile`

```
tap 'neovim/neovim'
brew "neovim", args: ['HEAD']
```

But with that and ran `brew bundle install`, I am still getting `neovim 0.4.4` with `nvim --version`

```
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: clang -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/tmp/neovim-20210318-48132-k7r45c/neovim-0.4.4/build/config -I/tmp/neovim-20210318-48132-k7r45c/neovim-0.4.4/src -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/tmp/neovim-20210318-48132-k7r45c/neovim-0.4.4/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tmp/neovim-20210318-48132-k7r45c/neovim-0.4.4/build/include
Compiled by brew@BigSur
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was probably an issue when 0.5 was being released. Now that 0.5.1 is stable, in your Brewfile, you should be able to just do

`brew "neovim"`

If you upgrade the formula, it will pull down latest stable which is 0.5.1 at the moment
`brew upgrade neovim`

Comment: Yes this should work now as neovim is in stable 0.5.0